# PHP - Calling a static method from the parent class

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I have the following class hierarchy: `MDLUser` inherits from `MDLPersistentObject`

In `MDLPersistentObject` I have a static method which returns an array. In `MDLUser` I override the static method so that it returns the `MDLPersistentObject`’s array, adds its own data, then returns the new array.

But when I call `parent::myArrayReturningMethod()` inside `MDLUser` it just returns `MDLUser`’s implementation (i.e. missing the array data from `MDLPersistentObject`. However, if I call it the bad practise way, `MDLPersistentObject::myArrayReturningMethod()`, then it returns what I expect.

Is `parent::` not the correct late static binding method for calling a parent implementation of a static method?

If you’re wondering what my code looks like:

MDLPersistentObject’s method:

```
static public function Neo4j_Labels_In_Client( Everyman\Neo4j\Client $client )
{
    //
    //  Create a label called `MDLPersistentObject`
    //

    $mdlobject_label = $client->makeLabel( get_called_class() );


    //
    //  Return the label in an array
    //

    $labels = Array(
        $mdlobject_label
    );

    return $labels;
}
```

MDLUser’s method:

```
static public function Neo4j_Labels_In_Client( Everyman\Neo4j\Client $client )
{
    //
    //  Get the parent labels
    //

    $labels = parent::Neo4j_Labels_In_Client( $client );

    //
    //  Add the new labels
    //

    $user_label = $client->makeLabel( get_called_class() );

    array_push( $labels, $user_label );


    //
    //  Return labels
    //

    return $labels;
}
```

Comment: Works as expected for me here: http://ideone.com/Kc11jN

Comment: Hmm, I’ll keep going over it and update as I go. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `get_called_class` isn't returning what you expect?

Comment: See this example: http://ideone.com/0aek2w `get_called_class` returns the class that was originally called, not the parent when inside the `parent::` method.

Comment: Does your child class actually extend the parent class?

Comment: `class MDLUser extends MDLPersistentObject`

Comment: So instead of using `get_called_class`, how do I get the current class in PHP?

Comment: Using `__CLASS__` instead of `get_called_class()` seems to work :)